# Photo stitching/panorama API/DLL/Library anyone?

Tags: photos, panoramas

For a special project, I need to find an API/DLL/Library to help me create a big image using parts of this image. For example, if someone take 4 pictures representing the 360 degrees around him, he will be able to create one big image (panorama) by stitching the 4 images together using special algorithm that recognize some patterns.

I know how to do this in Photoshop and I know there are a lot of programs that to this on the internet. But I want one that will be controlled by programming. This can be in C, C++, or .NET. If you have something in another language, you can tell answer too, I may consider to write a wrapper.

Comment: You can try this api: http://techcrunch.com/2012/08/10/dmd-panorama-api/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was looking for the same thing and I've found [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/automatic_panoramas.aspx).
It is a .net framework that can manipulate images. It can stitch together 2 images using 4 steps :

1. Interest point detection
2. Correlation matching
3. Robust homography estimation
4. Gradient blending

The demo covers only the stitching of 2 pictures at a time, but the code can be modified to stitch more pictures into one.
It is easy to use and it is **open source**.

Comment: Seems good but since my original post, we moved away from that solution (I'm in a R&D Department so things are moving fast!) But best solution so far, I'll mark you as the solution.

Comment: Since that time, I had to use Accord.NET for something else and it's an amazing Library and it work really well for image stitching.

Comment: thx for the update. You can answer your own question and accept it in order to help others with updated info.

Comment: I only try the demo for image stitching so I did not dig and see all the possibilities since that was not what I was asked for, so I'll keep your answer as the best !

Answer (score 3):

As far as i know Hugin is best which comes with source for both mac and windows

http://hugin.sourceforge.net/

It's using one of the best stitching algorithm which many industry big names in this field use it

Also Take a look at [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/)

and [pano12](http://panotools.sourceforge.net/) from panotools which is core of ptstitcher

**And**

For preview your pano files use devalvr

http://www.devalvr.com/

u can extract installer and use ocx within installer it's fastest for stand-alone projects with many parameters , commands , methods , etc

Answer (score 3):

This is used by GIMP as well **http://stitchpanorama.sourceforge.net/**

Answer (score 3):

SharpStitch is an image alignment and stitching library for .NET:

http://imagingshop.com/sharpstitch

It can create panoramic mosaics as well.

The library can do automatic stitching in a simple command or or perform one of the specific tasks (feature detection, feature matching, bundle adjustment / optimization, blending and rendering)

We as authors are open to add new features and improvements upon user's request. We are also developing GUI tools such as panorama viewer (using WPF).

Here is an a typical output of SharpStitch library:

[image]

Comment: Just wanted to point out that this software has a 5,000 USD entrance fee

Comment: @ThorSummoner 995 USD, the higher price is for full source code

Comment: Under which licence ?

Comment: @RzR Depends on usage; use the contact form on the webpage.

Answer (score 2):

This looks promising:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/panotools/