# photo stiching library for .net

Tags: image-processing

Does anyone know any photo stitching library that I can incorporate in a .net project to stitch some photos? Basically the user takes 3 photos and than the library crates a panoramic image by stitching his photos.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Photo stitching/panorama API/DLL/Library anyone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335689/photo-stitching-panorama-api-dll-library-anyone)

Comment: possible duplicate of [how-to-stitch-images-with-very-little-overlap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684440/how-to-stitch-images-with-very-little-overlap). And you can see [Automatic Image Stitching with Accord.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/95453/Automatic-Image-Stitching-with-Accord-NET), with demo and source code.

Answer (score 1):

You may try **SharpStitch**:

http://www.imagingshop.com/sharpstitch

It is a complete solution for image stitching, including panoramic image mosaics. This is an actual output of the library:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The open source [libpano](http://panotools.sourceforge.net/) project should work from .NET, as it is coded in C. This is the library that is used by [Hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/).